# SQL result table for predefined value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table:

```
Col A     Col B
----------------
493       0.08
467       0.1
432       0.13
429       0.13
378       0.2
354       0.25
334       0.3
297       0.38
271       0.45
255       0.5
223       0.68
```

I need results in this format:

```
Col A     Col B
---------------
467       0.1
378       0.2
334       0.3
null      0.4
228       0.5
...
...
62       100.0
```

So a need value from my table where col B has a value from 0 to 100 with step of 0.1

- If this value exists in my table, then Col A value is the result from my table
- If this value does not exist in my table, then result is NULL

My idea was to create virtual table where col A is always NULL and Col B are numbers from 0 to 100 with 0.1 steps  after that I can create right join of original table with result and this virtual table.

But I don't know how to create this virtual table in query.

Comment: Are you using mysql or postgres? Please tag only the RDBMS that you are using.

Comment: See: [generate_series()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-srf.html) for PostgreSQL and [Sequence Storage Engine](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/sequence-storage-engine/) for MariaDB.

Comment: I am using Dbeaver and database is postgresql

Answer (score 1):

In Postgres, you can proceed as follow:

- use `generate_series()` to generate a table of numbers from 0 to 100, with a 0.1 increment
- `LEFT JOIN` that with your original table

Query:

```
SELECT t.col_a, x.n as col_b
FROM generate_series(0, 100, 0.1) as x(n)
LEFT JOIN mytable t ON t.col_b = x.n
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/efftfJTiBeNLuLagK72kvv/1)**:

```
| col_a | col_b |
| ----- | ----- |
|       | 0     |
| 467   | 0.1   |
| 378   | 0.2   |
| 334   | 0.3   |
|       | 0.4   |
| 255   | 0.5   |
|       | 0.6   |
...
```

Comment: unfortunately  it does not work. Query execution failed

Reason:
SQL Error [42000]: ERROR: Only relations and subqueries are allowed in the FROM clause

Comment: Are you using Postgres? This works fine in the db fiddle link that I put in my answer.

Comment: Yes, I am using Postgres, version is 9.2.1-2 . i read that generate_series does not work on versions older than 8.4
On 9.2 it should work but it doesn't work.
Is there another option for me to make a series like this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
select floor(b * 1000) / 1000, min(a)
from t
group by floor(b * 1000) / 1000;
```

Note:  This will not returns the `NULL` value.  For filling that in, knowing the database would be helpful.

In Postgres, you would do:

```
select gs.val, min(t.a)
from generate_series(0, 100, 0.1) gs(val) left join
     t
     on t.b >= gs.val and t.b < gs.val + 0.1
group by gs.val
order by gs.val;
```

If you want an exact match, then use `t.b = gs.val`.  Be careful, though, if the values are floating point.

Comment: Thanks. It is postgreSQL database. but this option will not give me value for those rows that are not in the first table and I also need them with the value NULL.

Answer (score 0):

For Postgres use generate_series with .1 step increment.

```
select ot.colA, vt.ColB
  from org_tab ot 
 right join (select generate_series ( 0, 100, .1) colB) vt 
         on (ot.ColB = vt.colB)
```